# Access textfield.text for textfield inside a cell of tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to extract the values inputted to a textfield. The problem is these textfields are defined programmatically in a cell of a tableview.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];
NSUInteger numOfRows=[userControls count];
for (int i =0; i<numOfRows; i++) {
    [self saveValueForRow:i];
}
```

}

```
#pragma save defaults
- (void)saveValueForRow :(int)index {
    NSString *userDataString=userEntryField.text; //how to access each text field, as this currently just accesses the first one in the table
    NSLog(userDataString);
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userDataString   forKey:[controlKeys objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

My instinct was to collect all the data after the view disappears. But I don't know how to access each different text field in each different cell.

Comment: after entering the text in the cell text field ,should user should tap any button to save the data or any other option....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the tag of cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method as:

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Now at the time of getting values of textField you need to first get the cell by indexPath like:

```
#pragma save defaults
- (void)saveValueForRow :(int)index {
NSIndexPath *nowIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];

NSString *userDataString = cell.userEntryField.text; //how to access each text field, as this currently just accesses the first one in the table
NSLog(userDataString);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userDataString   forKey:[controlKeys objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `tag` for each `UITextField` like:

```
//...
textview.tag = indexPath.row;
//...
```

So after you can access each `textField` by `tag`. I hope this can help you.